# DELETE from table syntax

Tags: mysql

I have a table with (amongst others) 2 columns (say`A` and `B`) with a `primary key` and one with a `timestamp` (say C). I would like to delete everything but the last XXX entries (when sorted by the timestamp). Could anyone help me out with the syntax? I guess it should be along the lines of:

> DELETE FROM Table WHERE A, B NOT IN (SELECT A, B FROM Table ORDER BY C
>   DESC LIMIT XXX)

Is that correct SQL?

Edit: Somehow this question got closed being a duplicate. The referred question however only has answers that apply to a table which has exactly one primary key (or index) .. how do I expand this to a table where there are two?

Comment: Have you tried the pseudo code you posted?

Comment: As a general rule, when running a delete, use a select statement to get the where clause to where it needs to be and works, and replace the `select * from` part to `delete from`

Comment: I don't understand .. the LIMIT 10 is included in a 'NOT IN' .. why would it delete those?

Comment: I misunderstood your question.

Comment: I don't know why this question has been downvoted.  Seems perfectly reasonable to me.

Comment: @eggyal yeah, I upvoted it too.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
DELETE FROM TABLE T1 INNER JOIN (SELECT A, B FROM TABLE ORDER BY C DESC LIMIT XXXX) AS T2 ON T1.A = T2.A AND T1.B = T2.B
```

in interior select you define conditions for delete.

Comment: But that deletes XXXXX entries doesn't it? I want to delete everything but those XXXXX entries.

Comment: maybe you can
DELETE FROM TABLE T1 left JOIN (SELECT A, B FROM TABLE ORDER BY C DESC LIMIT XXXX) AS T2 ON T1.A = T2.A AND T1.B = T2.B where T2.A is null AND T2.B is null 

now you are delete where row  is not join